# Nginx location group capture + rewrite

Tags: nginx, pcre

I'm trying to do a group capture in a Nginx location block and it's not working for me.

Is what I am trying to do even possible?

```
location ~* /(?<cat>cars|trucks|bikes|motorcycle|quads) {
    rewrite ^/$cat/([0-9]+)(.*)$ /page.php?id=$1 last;
}
```

The error message I am receiving is :

"^/$cat/([0-9]+)(.*)$" does not match "/cars/120/new-car-rentals/"

I have a lot more categories than what I am posting, and trying to prevent writing a rewrite 5x for each specific category name.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with this particular syntax, but based on my experience with others, is it possible that you simply need to escape the forward slashes you're using?

```
location ~* \/(?<cat>cars|trucks|bikes|motorcycle|quads) {
    rewrite ^\/$cat\/([0-9]+)(.*)$ /page.php?id=$1 last;
}
```

Note the named capture in the `location` regex: if you want to use a value captured here, you must use the named syntax `(?<name>)`, numbers do not work.

Comment: I've never needed to escape the forward slashes on my other rewrites. This is where I got the syntax from : http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names

Comment: You don't need to escape slashes in nginx config, because it does not use slashes as regex delimiters. They are just another character there.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by doing this instead :

```
location ~* /(cars|trucks|bikes|motorcycle|quad-bikes) {
    rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z-]+)/([0-9]+)(.*)$ /page.php?id=$2 last;
    ...
    ...
}
```

The regex ([a-zA-Z-]+) allows me to use characters a-z (case insensitive) with possible dashes in my category / page names.

Comment: To match a path part (a bunch of not-slashes between slashes) we can also use negative character class like `/[^/]+/`. I use it myself pretty often.